# Вызов переменной в foreach с метода

Tags: php, ооп, telegram-bot

Привет всем. Задача вроде как несложная, но не могу найти решение. Это Telegram-бот, поэтому не всё так просто.

В базе есть таблица `models`, в таблице `models` есть поле `photo` в которой хранится названия файла в папке на сервере.
Теперь, есть класс, который осуществляет пагинацию по всем элементам и выводит данные каждого элемента на странице.
Нужно получить поле `photo` для каждой страницы.
Метод `getPaginationContent` проводит разбор по всем данным в таблице и выводит их в тексте. Но поле `photo` мне нужно получить в методе `execute`.

Заранее спасибо!

Надеюсь, объяснил понятно, если будут вопросы - спрашивайте.

```
<?php
namespace Longman\TelegramBot\Commands\AdminCommands;

use Longman\TelegramBot\Commands\UserCommand;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\CallbackQuery;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Request;
use TelegramBot\InlineKeyboardPagination\Exceptions\InlineKeyboardPaginationException;
use TelegramBot\InlineKeyboardPagination\InlineKeyboardPagination;

class GirlsCommand extends UserCommand
{
    protected $name = 'girls';
    protected $description = 'Каталог моделей - девушки.';
    protected $usage = '/girls';
    protected $version = '1.0.0';
    protected static $per_page = 1;

    public static function callbackHandler(CallbackQuery $query)
    {
        $params = InlineKeyboardPagination::getParametersFromCallbackData($query->getData());
        if ($params['command'] !== 'girls') {
            return null;
        }

        $data = [
            'chat_id'    => $query->getMessage()->getChat()->getId(),
            'message_id' => $query->getMessage()->getMessageId(),
            'text'       => 'Empty',
        ];

        // Using pagination
        if ($pagination = self::getInlineKeyboardPagination($params['newPage'])) {
            $data['text']         = self::getPaginationContent($pagination['items']);
            $data['reply_markup'] = [
                'inline_keyboard' => [$pagination['keyboard']],
            ];
        }

        return Request::editMessageText($data);
    }

    public static function getModels()
    {
        // Получаем список моделей с базы
        return DB::getPdo()->query('SELECT * FROM `models_girls`')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public static function getPaginationContent(array $items)
    {
        $text = '';

        foreach ($items as $row) {
            $text .= "Имя: $row['id']\n";
            $text .= "Параметры: $row['name']\n";
            $text .= "Размер одежды: $row['message']\n";
        }

        return $text;
    }

    public static function getInlineKeyboardPagination($page = 1)
    {
        $models   = self::getModels();

        if (empty($models)) {
            return null;
        }

        // Define inline keyboard pagination.
        $ikp = new InlineKeyboardPagination($models, 'girls', $page, self::$per_page);

        // If item count changes, take wrong page clicks into account.
        try {
            $pagination = $ikp->getPagination();
        } catch (InlineKeyboardPaginationException $e) {
            $pagination = $ikp->getPagination(1);
        }

        return $pagination;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = [
            'chat_id' => $this->getMessage()->getChat()->getId(),
            'text'    => 'Empty',
        ];

        /**
         *
         */
        if ($pagination = self::getInlineKeyboardPagination(1)) {
            $data['text']         = self::getPaginationContent($pagination['items']);
            $data['reply_markup'] = [
                'inline_keyboard' => [$pagination['keyboard']],
            ];
        }

        return Request::sendMessage($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно вот так:

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $this->getMessage()->getChat()->getId(),
        'text'    => 'Empty',
    ];

    $request = DB::getPdo()->prepare('SELECT count(*) as count FROM `models_girls`')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $pages = $request['count']/self::$per_page;

    foreach($pages as $page){
        if ($pagination = self::getInlineKeyboardPagination($page)) {
            $data[]=[
                'text'=>self::getPaginationContent($pagination['items']),
                'reply_markup'=>[
                    'inline_keyboard' => [$pagination['keyboard']],
                ];
            ];
        }
    }


    return Request::sendMessage($data);
}
```

Получаем кол-во записей, делем на количетво отображаемых на страницу, получаем кол-во страниц, проходим циклом что бы получить данные с всех страниц, и заносим в массив (тут уж не знаю в каком види вам они там нужны)

Ну или измените ваш метод `self::getInlineKeyboardPagination` добавив вторым параметром кол-во записей на страницу:

```
public static function getInlineKeyboardPagination($page = 1, $per_page=null)
{
    $per_page = empty($per_page)?self::$per_page:$per_page;
    ...
    $ikp = new InlineKeyboardPagination($models, 'girls', $page, $per_page);
    ...
}

public function execute()
{
    ...
    $request = DB::getPdo()->prepare('SELECT count(*) as count FROM `models_girls`')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ...
    if ($pagination = self::getInlineKeyboardPagination($request['count'])) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Передав вторым параметров кол-во записей в базе, он вытащит сразу все данные.

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ.
Немного не понимаю. По первой функции - такой массив не работает я про ($data[][]), даже в коде ошибку выдаёт. И в чём фишка такого решения? Мне просто нужно вытащить поле `photo` в каждой модели (элемента на странице)
А по второму варианту - проблема в том, что в таблице есть поле `id` AUTO_INCREMENT и оно может равняться и 1 для первой страницы и 140 для второй страницы, и так далее. И если выводить записи в соответствии с номером страницы, это не совсем то, что нужно. Надеюсь Вы понимаете. Буду признателен Вашей помощи, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что то понаписывал с ошибками, поправил что из явного вижу. Если вам нужны и номера страниц, то второй вариант вам конечно не подойдет, он просто выдернет все записи. Массив не работает - поправил, то написал ересь, а фишек нет, просто в массив закидывает, исправьте на то что вам нужно на выходе. В любом случае, я всегда пишу идею, в деталях/ошибках вам там уже самому легче разобраться по сообщению из тех жи ошибок.

Comment: Уважаемые минусующие, если у вас есть время разобраться в вопросе, разобраться в ответе, и поминусовать, пожалуйста найдите время прокомментировать ваши минусы, спасибо

Comment: @MyZik возможно не правильно понял задачу, вам нужно со всех страниц получить записи или только с текущей страницы?

Comment: смотрите :)
Проводится листинг всех записей в таблице и они уютно располагаются на каждой странице. Снизу кнопочки типа "1", "2", "...", "10" и т.д.
По сути, нужно знать, где получаются данные конкретной записи в таблице на конкретной странице. Выходит, что мне нужно получить поле `photo` для текущей страницы.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну значит для текущей страницы а не все страницы, у вас в коде вы передаете в метод `self::getInlineKeyboardPagination` значение `1`, то есть первую страницу, вередайте туда номер страницы ну и все. Как его получить? Тут я вам не помогу, ну наверное ж какие до данные приходят в execute метод.

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, то нужно поковырять библиотеку.
Могу я как-то связаться с Вами? Буду крайне признателен.

Comment: я вам тут не помогу, я не работал с этой библиотекой, но подозреваю что вам сюда - https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/pull/438

Comment: да, именно с этой библиотекой работаю.
Вот само дополнение по листингу предметов: https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/inline-keyboard-pagination
А вот мой issue на github: https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/issues/589
Проблема в том, что листинг идёт через отправку простого текстового сообщения: `Request::sendMessage`, а мне нужна отправка фотографии `Request::sendPhoto`, но нужно так же указывать путь к фотографии, и чтобы она не была одинаковой на каждой странице, пытаюсь получить адрес фотографии текущей записи в БД, которая отображается в таблице.